# Is there a way to distribute different architectures separately?

Tags: ios, iphone, build, app-store, ipa

This might come off as an awkward question, so let me explain the background:

The goal is to try to reduce the app size on itunes.

I've noticed that with the increase of 64 bit builds, it bumped the size of the app bundle from 30 MB to 55 MB or something like that. My understanding is that something like the iphone 6 is going to use 64 bit architecture. But for an iphone 4s, can they just download a 30 MB binary?

Comment: Not until iOS 9 - See App Thinning - https://developer.apple.com/ios/pre-release/ https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html

Comment: @Paulw11 oh wow. that's actually really cool!!! you should put your comment as an answer, because that's actually the answer in the future whenever they release iOS 9!! Also - could you tell from the description if the app thinning part is done for you automatically? or do you have to submit 3 different ipas?

Comment: It will be done automatically

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9 onwards, apple is doing that. It will create variants of app for different devices, mainly depending on the multiple resolutions of images in the asset catalog. This will provide different size of your app for different devices.